# Flutter список без прокрутки

Tags: flutter

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как сделать не прокручиваемы список. Или как можно, распарсить данные.

Есть код:

```
final List<SlickList> itemsSlickList = [SlickList(name: 'имя',url: 'url',),SlickList(name: 'имя',url: 'url',),SlickList(name: 'имя',url: 'url',),];
     Container(
        height: 132,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: itemsSlickList.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) => ProductCardSlider(
            item: itemsSlickList[index],
            width: 250,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

У меня есть Widget ProductCardSlider, мне нужно пройтись по нему и распарсить данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return Column(
  children: List<Widget>.generate(
    itemsSlickList.length,
    (int i) => ProductCardSlider(
      item: itemsSlickList[i],
      width: 250,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Благодарю, за столь быстрый ответ!